# Creating a funnel using a pivot table in R considering NA column

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have the following dataset:

```
library(tidyverse)
dataset <- data.frame(id = c(121,122,123,124,125), 
                      segment = c("A","B","B","A",NA), 
                      Web = c(1,1,1,1,1),
                      Tryout = c(1,1,1,0,1), 
                      Purchase = c(1,0,1,0,0), 
                      stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

This table as you see converts to a funnel, from web visits (the quantity of rows), to tryout to a purchase. So a useful view of this funnel should be:

```
Step     Total    A    B    NA
Web      5        2    2    1
Tryout   4        1    2    1
Purchase 2        1    1    0
```

So I tried row by row doing this. The web views code is:

```
dataset %>% mutate(segment = ifelse(is.na(segment), "NA", segment)) %>% 
  group_by(segment) %>% summarise(Total = n()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% spread(segment, Total) %>% mutate(Total = `A` + `B` + `NA`) %>% 
  select(Total,A,B,`NA`)
```

And worked fine, except that I have to put manually the row name. But for the other steps like tryout and purchase, is there a way to do it in just one simpler code, avoiding binding? Consider that this is an example and I have many columns so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option where we convert the data to 'long' format after removing the 'id' column, grouped by 'name' get the `sum` of 'value', then grouped by 'segment', 'Total' as well and do the second `sum`, get the `distinct` rows and pivot back to 'wide' format

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dataset %>% 
   select(-id) %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = -segment) %>%
   group_by(name) %>%
   mutate(Total = sum(value)) %>% 
   group_by(name, segment, Total) %>%
   mutate(n = sum(value)) %>% 
   ungroup  %>%
   select(-value) %>% 
   distinct %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = segment, values_from = n)
# A tibble: 3 x 5
#  name     Total     A     B  `NA`
#  <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 Web          5     2     2     1
#2 Tryout       4     1     2     1
#3 Purchase     2     1     1     0
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun, the code worked fine! Just a question, why distinct doesn't use parenthesis? I mean, its like a function and I used to see code with that as `distinct()`, even inside the pipes.

Comment: @Manu you can use any function mean, median etc without ().  If you are calling it from namespace i.e. `dplyr::distinct`, it may need ().  otherwise, it would apply the function implicitly on the output coming from the `%>%`

Comment: Thank you @akrun, now I understand how to skip using the parenthesis. Have a great day!

Answer (score 2):

```
dataset %>%
    select(-id) %>%
    group_by(segment) %>%
    summarise_all(sum) %>%
    gather(Step, val, -segment) %>%
    spread(segment, val) %>%
    mutate(Total = rowSums(.[,-1]))
```

Comment: Hello @sda, thank you. Just a question, in your rowSums function, I see a dot/period as `rowSums( . [,-1])`, could you please tell me if that dot/period replace all columns from segment?

Comment: @Manu, yes it dropped `segment` but only for calculating the `rowSums`